# How can I make my spreadsheet add one data point per day automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I have a spreadsheet with data that auto updates, I want to have a visualization of how that data changes over time, I tried using some other tutorials but some of the methods seemed way over complicated for just copying one data point a day.

I have this but I do not know what to do with it, when I hit run it makes the data point like it should, but it does not do it automatically per day.

```
function Copy() {

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my id here'); 

var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 

var range = ss.getRange('L3'); 

var data = range.getValues();


var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my id here'); 

var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,1,1).setValues(data);

}
```

Basically I just want it to copy data from one cell onto another cell, (a new cell each day)

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Comment: Rather than going for so much pain you can get this visualization by default in google sheets by either watching the change history of the complete sheet or right clicking a cell to see its edit history.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a time trigger to your script.

In script editor use:
Edit --> Current project's triggers
Then add trigger
[image]

Then set time driven trigger

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run createTrigger. It will only create one trigger with the function name.

```
function saveL3() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById();
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh2.appendRow([sh1.getRange('L3').getValue()]);
}

function createTrigger() {
  const triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  let names=triggers.map(function(t){return t.getHandlerFunction()});
  if(names.indexOf('saveL3')==-1) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('saveL3').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(1).create();
  };
}
```